# Can't get the right permissions to a shared folder

Tags: permissions

I'm trying to set a shared directory in my server. There is 2 developper and they will work on the same directory.

I created a directory, change the group owner to www-data and chmod it to 755 :

```
drwxrwsr-x  3 root www-data 4096 2012-08-24 12:06 SharedDir/
```

But when i log in my directory with one dev login and try to touch a files it create a file with 644 perms

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 user1 www-data    0 2012-08-24 12:11 test
```

How can i create a mask to set the perms to 755 by default ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to set the [umask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask) on the directory.

Comment: How ? i tried to put a umask 0002 in a .bashrc but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the execute bit set on files as default it isn't possible with umask. Because umask always is calculated from the maximum/base rights a "thing" can have.

directories: 777
files: 666